# How do I ask for a collection of n data points (x and y coordinates) until the java program reads a blank line from the first coordinate?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop, linked-list

**My question is regarding this exercise:**

> Write an algorithm that reads a collection of points from the user. The user will
> enter the first  coordinate, followed by the first  coordinate. Allow the user
> to continue entering coordinates until your program reads a blank line for the
>  coordinate. Display the formula for the line of best fit in the form  =  + 
> by replacing  and  with the calculated values.

**Using the following formulas:**

[image: line of best fit formula]

**My problem is:**

I don't know how to stop asking for coordinates once the program reads a blank space only in the x coordinate. Does it even make sense?

**I can imagine multiple cases:**

*Case 1*

> 3     --- 1st input (x coordinate)
>
> 2     --- 2nd input (y coordinate)
>
> BLANK --- 3rd input. End of loop, we do our calculations.

*Case 2*

> BLANK --- 1st input (x coordinate). End of loop, we can't do any calculations.

*Case 3*

> 3     --- 1st input (x coordinate)
>
> BLANK --- 2nd input. Ask for the y coordinate.
>
> 1     --- 3rd input (y coordinate)
>
> BLANK --- 4th input. End of loop, we do our calculations.

**My code trying to achieve those conditions is the next one:**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> exes = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> ys = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Please enter your x coordinate: ");
    String badNumber = null;
    Integer goodNumber = null;
    var counter = 0;
    while (!(badNumber = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) { //only leave when there is a blank line from the x coordinate
        try {
            goodNumber = Integer.parseInt(badNumber);
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                exes.add(goodNumber);
            } else {
                ys.add(goodNumber);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Please insert a valid number");
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your x coordinate: ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter your y coordinate: ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't find any issues. I tried your code and it works as expected, it stops after inserting nothing... But I got one issue: if you input an invalid number, `counter` is incremented as well so the following coordinates may not be placed as expected

Comment: Hi @StefanWarminski ! First of all, thank you for your answer. The issue is that I don't wan't it to stop after inserting nothing but after inserting nothing when asking for the x coordinate because we need to have x and y together. I will check that counter variable though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add `|| counter % 2 != 0` to your `while` condition.
So you only stop if the input is empty and you're at x-coordinate.
If you also move `counter++;` into `try` to only increase it if the value was added succesfully the output may look like:

```
Please enter your x coordinate: 
1
Please enter your y coordinate: 
2
Please enter your x coordinate: 
3
Please enter your y coordinate: 

Please insert a valid number
Please enter your y coordinate: 
4
Please enter your x coordinate:
```